# Outer join or union all to transform the rows into columns

Tags: sql, join, hive, union-all

**What I have:** table

```
 _______________________________________            
 | MachUUID | State|  Pass   | Fail    |   
 |--------------------------------------
 |  1234    | A    |   0.2   |    0.98 |  
 |  1234    | B    |   0.5   |    0.5  |  
 |  1234    | C    |   0.8   |    0.2  |
 ---------------------------------------
```

**What I want** : transformed_table

```
 | MachUUID | A_Pass | A_Fail | B_Pass | B_Fail | C_Pass | C_Fail
  --------------------------------------------------------------
 |  1234    |  0.2   | 0.98   |  0.5   |  0.5   | 0.8    |  0.2
```

The number of states (A, B etc are fixed). They are up to 20 of these at the moment. So to transform this

**What I am doing**:

```
Transformed_Table AS (
SELECT MachUUID, Pass AS A_Pass, Fail AS A_Fail
FROM table
WHERE State = 'A'
UNION ALL

SELECT MachUUID, Pass AS B_Pass, Fail AS B_Fail
FROM table
WHERE State = 'B'
UNION ALL

SELECT MachUUID, Pass AS C_Pass, Fail AS C_Fail
FROM table
WHERE State = 'C')
```

However, this returns a weird union which looks something like :

**Erroneous output I am getting**

```
| MachUUID | A_Pass| A_Fail |
|   1234   | 0.2   | 0.98   |
|   1234   | 0.5   | 0.5    |
|   1234   | 0.8   | 0.2    |
```

**Question**

I think my understanding of union is incorrect at this point. I understand outerjoins and am wondering if that's a better way of doing this.

I am open to suggestions for other ways to tackle this

Comment: The common pivot technique uses GROUP BY and conditional aggregates: https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: @MarkusWinand the problem with the linked approach is that, I have to use a case statement like `CASE state = 'A' then Pass End As A_Pass` `CASE state = 'A' then Fail End As A_Fail`. I am not sure that if I had 2 case statements evaluating the exact same case, both of them would be executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select MachUUID,
       max(case when state = 'A' then pass end) as a_pass,
       max(case when state = 'A' then fail end) as a_fail,
       max(case when state = 'B' then pass end) as b_pass,
       max(case when state = 'B' then fail end) as b_fail,
       max(case when state = 'C' then pass end) as c_pass,
       max(case when state = 'C' then fail end) as c_fail
from t
group by MachUUID
```

Comment: From some literature I was reading, my understanding was that, if I had two cases, both evaluating exactly the same condition, RDBMS would be smart to not check both.

Comment: @ExceptionHandler . . . That might be true in some databases, but this is a micro-optimization compared to the work of moving around data.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you comment. I am worried if it optimizes this way, I will never get the full picture. As in, having this optimization would actually screw up the results.

Comment: @ExceptionHandler . . . I don't understand your concern.  If the `then` part of the `case` expression is ignored, that would be a bug.  The result set should be what the query expresses.